# how to sort list according certain criterion

Tags: python, list, sorting

for example I have a list

```
list = [['word1', 0.234], ['word2', 0.2], ['word3', 0.5], ['word4', 0,67]]
```

and I want to sort it by importance. Importance means how far is the value from 0.5. The list after sorting should be:

```
list = [['word2', 0.2], ['word1', 0.234], ['word4', 0.67], ['word3', 0,5]]
```

First I solved it by writing simple function based on bubble sorting but it's very slow.

```
def most_interesting_words(seznam):
"""sort list i.e. [['word', spamicity], ...], first tokens whose value was furthest from the neutral value of 
for i in range(len(seznam)):
    for j in range(len(seznam)):
        #if dist_from_05(seznam[i][1]) > dist_from_05(seznam[j][1]):
        if abs(0.5 - seznam[i][1]) > abs(0.5 - seznam[j][1]):
            tmp = seznam[i]
            seznam[i] = seznam[j]
            seznam[j] = tmp
return seznam
```

How it can be solved with sorted() function?

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Maciek I'm using python 3. Anyway the problem is solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To sort by distance from `0.5` you can use the following `sorted()` function:

```
my_list = [['word1', 0.234], ['word2', 0.2], ['word3', 0.5], ['word4', 0.67]]
print(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: abs(0.5 - x[1]), reverse=True))
```

This would give you the following output:

```
[['word2', 0.2], ['word1', 0.234], ['word4', 0.67], ['word3', 0.5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the parameter `key`. Example

```
myList = [['word1', 0.234], ['word2', 0.2], ['word3', 0.5], ['word4', 0.67]]
print(sorted(myList,key= lambda x: abs(0.5-x[1]),reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[[word2, 0.2], [word1, 0.234], [word4, 0.67], [word3, 0.5]]
```

If you want to actually sort you list and not create a new one use `myList.sort(key= lambda x: abs(0.5-x),reverse=True)` instead

Comment: Your output doesn't match the desired output shown in the question; word4 should be the third element in the sorted list.

Comment: It matches, problem was word4 number was misswriten (`0,67` instead of `0.67`), corrected