# how to sort a list of lists by self defined function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting

I'm working on my small "homework". and i'd like to sort a list of lists with a function, which i defined.

for exp.

```
list = [[1], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
function1: (the length of every small list) / 10
function2: (the length of every small list) / 12
and the first 3 lists judged by function1, and the other by function2
```

what i want for result:

```
list = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

i can already sort the list by its length without the function, so please let me know if you have any ideas. 
thanks!

Comment: Sorting by length of list / 10 is exactly the same as sorting by length of the list...

Comment: Side note: As long as you're not doing integer division (rounding down when you have a fractional division result), there's not point in keeping the `/ 10`, the sort order will be the same anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort list according certain criterion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940432/how-to-sort-list-according-certain-criterion)

Comment: sorry for that, it's because in my homework there are 2 different functions, the other one is: length of the list / 12.

Comment: it's already updated, first time here, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement it with built-in `sorted()` function. You can specify how you want to sort the elements of your iterable by providing an additional function as a `key`. Here you want to sort by length of the elements (i.e length of inner lists), so you can use built-in `len()` function. You can also implement a custom lambda function.

```
alist = [[1], [1,2,3,4], [1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
sorted_list = sorted(alist, key=len)
print(sorted_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: For the love of Guido, please make that Python 3 friendly. Bonus points for at least a sentence to explain what's happening here.

Comment: yeap. gimme a sec

Comment: There is not so much to explain here.. I bet that googling the title of the question would lead OP to the answer in less than a minute

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Sure. But if an answer is to be provided, it should still be a complete answer. Alternatively, if a question is a clear dupe, then it should also be flagged as such before jumping to an answer as well.

Comment: It is definately important to say that this code does not sort the list `alist`. It creates a new list that is the sorted version of `alist`. `alist.sort(key=..)` is in-place sorting

Comment: @idjaw Shall I delete this?

Comment: @MYGz Not necessarily. My comment was more general. Also, you provided more meat around the answer too. No worries. :)